# biggest values indecies by sub-grouping 2D array : argwhere.sort.max.group.sum(axis=1)?

Tags: python, numpy, max, 2d, grouping

Let say I have 2D array :

```
  a = np.random.randint(0,10,(20,5))
```

I want to get the two max row sums row-indexes, but looking at them as groups.

So in this case I want to split the 20 rows in 5 groups, get the .sum(axis=1) and pick the maximum in the group.

After I have the five maximums (for every group), I want to pick the **two** biggest values row-indexes (based on the original array)

```
  a.sum(axis=1)
  ... get max in all 5 groups
  ... pick two biggest
  ... argwhere() of those two
```

---

```
  asum.reshape((4,5))

 array([[18, 27, 23, 18, 26],
   [34, 24, 23, 15, 30],
   [16, 26, 21, 24, 16],
   [21, 24, 29, 23, 23]])



  a.sum(axis=1).reshape((4,5)).argmax(axis=1)
  Out[55]: array([1, 0, 1, 2])
```

now I have to convert those to 1D indexes..

```
  idxs = a.sum(axis=1).reshape((4,5)).argmax(axis=1) + np.arange(0,4) * 5
  array([ 1,  5, 11, 17])
```

now I have to pick top two, given those indecies !?

hmm... ugly..

```
 : asum
 array([18, 27, 23, 18, 26, 34, 24, 23, 15, 30, 16, 26, 21, 24, 16, 21, 24, 29, 23, 23])

idxs[np.argsort(asum[idxs])][::-1][:2] 
array([ 5, 17])
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.random.randint(0,10,(20,5))
row_sums = a.sum(axis=1)

# array([30, 23, 13, 26, 17, 27, 29, 21, 16, 25, 21, 23, 38, 32, 23, 18, 16,
#        23, 16, 25])
```

This solution avoids a complete sort by using a binary heap:

```py
N = 2
import heapq
index_and_max = heapq.nlargest(N, enumerate(row_sums), key=lambda x: x[1])

# list of tuple of index and value at index, of two largest
#[(12, 38), (13, 32)]
```

Otherwise, you can stick with `numpy` arrays' built in `argsort`

```
row_sums.argsort()[-2:]
# array([13, 12])
```

Comment: but isnt this general max, i need sort-of-group-max